# What is mean and median of $X$ if $P(X \geq \frac{1}{2}+x)=P(X \leq \frac{1}{2}-x)$?

Tags: probability, expected-value, median

> Let $X$ be a random variable such that $E[X] < \infty$ and $P(X \geq \frac{1}{2}+x)=P(X \leq \frac{1}{2}-x),  \forall x \in R$ then find $E(X)$ and median$(X)$.

My attempt:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{1}{2}-x} f(t) dt = \int_{\frac{1}{2}+x}^{+\infty} f(t) dt \\ E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x f(x) dx $

Now i tried splitting interval into $(-\infty,\frac{1}{2}-x], [\frac{1}{2}-x, \frac{1}{2}+x] , [\frac{1}{2}+x, +\infty)$ and intergrate by parts. But i am not to proceed. Kindly tell me how to proceed

---

[image]

Comment: Hint : For mediane use definition

Comment: @EDX sir at 0 i am getting $P(X \leq 0) = 1 = P(X \geq 0)$. Defination says if m is median then $P(X \leq m) \geq \frac{1}{2} , P(X \geq m) \geq \frac{1}{2}$. It means 0 is median right. But intuitively, at median, area under pdf curve should be 1/2 on both sides of x  = median. But defination says it is more than 1/2. That is where i am surprised. Total area under pdf curve = 1. So at median curve area on either side = 1/2 (why greater than 1/2?)

Comment: In the special cases where $P(X\leq m)>\frac12$ for median $m$ a "pdf curve" does not exist, because in that case the distribution is not continuous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that: $$P\left(X\geq \frac{1}{2}+x\right)=P\left(X\leq \frac{1}{2}-x\right)\text{ for all }x\in\mathbb R$$tells us that:$$X-\frac{1}{2}\stackrel{d}{=}\frac{1}{2}-X$$ so that - if $\mathbb{E}X$
exists - we have: $$\mathbb{E}X-\frac{1}{2}=\mathbb{E}\left(X-\frac{1}{2}\right)=\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{2}-X\right)=\frac{1}{2}-\mathbb{E}X$$
or equivalently: $$\mathbb{E}X=\frac{1}{2}$$

$m$ is a median iff: $$P\left(X\geq m\right)\geq\frac{1}{2}\text{ and }P\left(X\leq m\right)\geq\frac{1}{2}$$
Observe that: $$P\left(X\geq \frac{1}{2}\right)=P\left(X\leq \frac{1}{2}\right)$$
and also: $$P\left(X\geq \frac{1}{2}\right)+P\left(X\leq \frac{1}{2}\right)=1+P\left(X=\frac12\right)\geq1$$
implying that: $$P\left(X\geq \frac{1}{2}\right)\geq\frac{1}{2}\text{ and }P\left(X\leq \frac{1}{2}\right)\geq\frac{1}{2}$$ This proves
that $\frac{1}{2}$ is a median.

It is not excluded that there are more medians though.

Comment: sir how did write the 1st statement. X- 1/2 = 1/2 - X

I am reading median defination in wiki. Intuitively in my mind, i feel that median is where cdf is halved right? it means P(X>=m) = 1/2 and P(X<=m) = 1/2 why is that in wiki and ur defination takes it more than 1/2. Pls explain

Comment: sir i understood 1st line and then how u wrote x-1/2 = 1/2 - x? i recently started studying this subject. Pardon my ignorance and request ur patiennce for more elaboration. Also pls clarify on median defination

Comment: Ok, u rearranged it right. P(X-0.5 >= x) = P(0.5 - X >= x). It means X-0.5 = 0.5 - X. Am i right?

Comment: I am not writing $X-1/2=1/2-X$ but $X-1/2\stackrel{d}{=}1/2-X$ which means that $X-1/2$ and $1/2-X$ have the same distribution. For that note that: $$P(X-1/2\geq x)=P(X\geq1/2+x)=P(X\leq1/2-x)=P(1/2-X\geq x)$$Further I use the [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Probability_distributions) for median. If a function is not continuous then it can happen that $P(X\geq m)=P(X\leq m)>1/2$ for median $m$. For instance let the CDF be the CDF $F(x)=1_{[0,\infty)}(x)$. In that case $m=0$ and $P(X\geq 0)=P(X\leq 0)=1$.

Comment: And $P(X \geq \frac{1}{2}) = P(X \leq \frac{1}{2})  \implies P(X \geq \frac{1}{2}) + P(X \leq \frac{1}{2}) = 1 $ only right? symmetric pdf curve? And for continuous pdf, point probabiity = 0 right? Pls elaborate

Comment: For every random variable $X$ and every constant $c\in\mathbb R$ we have $P(X\geq c)+P(X\leq c)=1+P(X=c)\geq1$.

Comment: sir can u pls see above median calculation for the CDF u have mentioned. I am getting $P(X \leq 0) = 1 = P(X \geq 0)$. Request your patience. Pls elaborate in ur convinient time. It is enlightening for me that i am learning from your answer by refering to wiki

Comment: If I understand you well then you are getting $P(X\leq0)=1=P(X\geq0)$ if the CDF of $X$ equals $1_{[0\infty)}(x)$. Well, that is correct and $m=0$ then satisfies the condition for being a median. What exactly do you want to be explained?

Comment: I am thinking median is where area under pdf curve is halved. Total area under pdf curve = 1. If it ihalved means left side area of median = 1/2 and right side area of median = 1/2. But in above example i am getting left side area of pdf curve is 1 and right side area of pdf curve = 1. Over all area of pdf curve = 1 for it to be a fundamental probability distribution right?(in defination of some function to be pdf, $\int_{-\intfy}^{+\infty} f(t) dt = 1$

Comment: I mean if left side area of median is more than 1/2 and right side area under pdf of median is more than half then overall area under pdf will be more than 1. Will this violate the defination that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t) dt = 1$

Comment: Your thinking is in a way polluted by PDF's. Yes, if there is a PDF then the distribution is continuous. And if a distribution is continuous then it will not occur that $P(X\leq m)=P(X\geq m)>1$. This because $P(X=m)=0$ in that case. But there are distributions that are not continuous. In that case there is no PDF  and it can occur that $P(X\leq m)=P(X\geq m)>1$. This is not contradicting anything concerning PDF simply because there is no PDF in that situation (so not a thing like "area under pdf curve"). Think of *discrete* distributions in that case.

Comment: understood now sir. Thank you for patiently explaining.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The condition, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

$$\mathbb{P}[X \leq \frac{1}{2}-x ]=\mathbb{P}[X \geq \frac{1}{2}+x ]$$

implies that the density of X is symmetric around $\frac{1}{2}$ and unimodal.

Thus Mean, Mode and Median is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: sir how did u vizualise. I recently started studying on my own. Kindly elaborate

Comment: sir I am thinking in this way. Pls correct if wrong. At 1/2, area of curve under pdf x distance less from 1/2 = area of curve under pdf x distance more from 1/2 and x can tend to 1/2. It means around 1/2, pdf curve is symmetric right? it means mean = 1/2

Comment: i am visualising analogous to normal pdf curve.

Comment: In the question it is not explicitly stated that a PDF exists.

Comment: @drhab sir P(X<= some function of x) exists means cdf exists. Does it mean pdf exists? pls correct if wrong

Comment: @tommik sir pls reply

Comment: @NascimentodeCos As I said: it does not mean that a PDF exists. Fortunately to solve the question you don't need a PDF.

Comment: @NascimentodeCos : I think that the given condition $F_X(\frac{1}{2}-x)=1-F_X(\frac{1}{2}+x)$ is an evident condition of symmetry around 1/2. Also if it is not a sufficient proof, try to visualize this condition on a Gaussian curve

Comment: @tommik sir, it look sufficient proof when i tried to visualise on normal pdf or gaussian pdf. I mean symetry of area around x=1/2 line right? THat is sufficient proof only right? i am not able to understand what u r refering to. pls elaborate

Comment: @NascimentodeCos : the analytic proof by dhrab is better than mine, elegant and general. Follow his calculations

Answer (score 1):

Let, $T_1 = X-\frac{1}{2}$

Now consider the another form of expectation using CDF function,

$$\mathbb{E}(T_1)= \int_0^{\infty}\big[\mathbb{P}(T_1>x)- \mathbb{P}(T_1\leq-x)\big]dx\\
=\int_0^{\infty}\big[\mathbb{P}(X>\frac{1}{2}+x)- \mathbb{P}(X\leq\frac{1}{2}-x)\big]dx\\
=0\\
\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}\big(X-\frac{1}{2}\big)=0\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{1}{2}$$

And for getting median $=\frac{1}{2}$, previous answers are enough.